# Maintain consistent design & chrome across multiple websites

Tags: html, architecture

In the same vein as the microservice architecture approach we're currently looking at splitting our legacy marketplace application into multiple, smaller sites. We've already carved off the checkout portion and soon to follow will be the seller portal, user portal and registration pages. Each site will be completely separate and have its own domain, data access etc.

The problem is: how do we maintain consistent site chrome (i.e. header & footer) across multiple websites? For the checkout site that we've already split off we were prepared to drop the site chrome but that's going to be a much less acceptable solution for future projects.

The ideas I've had so far are (assuming we don't want to simply duplicate the header and footer in each site):

- Put the necessary HTML in a nuget package and install it in each site that needs it. This should be fairly easy to do but has the disadvantage that any change to the chrome means every site needs to be updated and redeployed. Also, it limits us to .NET for all future sites (maybe not a real concern?).
- Serve all our sites through some kind of proxy site that injects the site chrome into the HTML before serving to the client. This way the site chrome is actually its own application and can be deployed independently of anything else. Disadvantage: I haven't really got any idea of how to implement this; I wasn't able to find anyone else trying anything similar on Google. Also, it might be fragile even once it's up and running due to interplay between the chrome app and the content app.

Has anyone else solved this problem before? If so, what approach did you use?

Comment: How are you serving the HTML at the moment? Are you serving them via the different application servers?

Comment: Yes, they're different applications that, although they currently run on the same servers, will be moved to separate servers soon.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to ask is if you're dynamically producing the HTML in your server code or are you providing an API for the JavaScript to render the HTML dynamically?

Comment: No, there's no Javascript here (at least, not that's relevant). All the HTML is generated server-side.

Comment: Whats the server application architecture? Is it like an MVC architecture? The reason I ask is because you may be able to create separate the templates as some kind of library and explicitly render the HTML directly. If not, the better solution might be to attempt to duplicate the HTML code structure along with a build out of a front end library (CSS and JavaScript) until a refactor can be put in place to create an API and a single page application.